# Running unity with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, unity-game-engine, pug

I'm using NodeJS with Express and trying to run a Unity html file on my site.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get a Unity html file I have to play on my NodeJS site. The files are `WebPlayer.html` and `WebPlayer.unity3d`. If I open up the local copy of `WebPlayer.html` in my browser, the game plays fine. However, if I try to run the game through my site, I get the message `Failed to download data file`. I've looked this up, and have seen people having the same issues as me, but couldn't find too many helpful suggestions from people using node. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

`Running the local copy in my browser (unity is loading the game and is working fine).`
 `file:///Users/thomasbaldwin/Desktop/WebPlayer.html`
[image]

`Running the WebPlayer.html file on my local server.`
`http://localhost:3000/account/game/`
[image]